# Can't add last xml version to flutter project

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

i created a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/idempierews_dart) that is depend from xml package last version 4.1.0, but when i tried to use the package that i create in flutter project the bellow error was thrown, i downgrade the xml version in my package to be able to use it but even if i tried to add xml to flutter project the same error is thrown, i am using the last flutter version channel beta, v1.17.0

> in idempierews_flutter...              Because every version of
>   flutter_test from sdk depends on xml 3.6.1 and idempierews_flutter
>   depends on xml ^4.1.0, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
>
> So, because idempierews_flutter depends on flutter_test any from sdk,
>   version solving failed. pub get failed (1; So, because
>   idempierews_flutter depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version
>   solving failed.) exit code 1*

I lost also -10 points from dart package analyses because i don't support latest dependencies :-(

Comment: I believe the dependency in Flutter has been solved a few days ago: https://github.com/dart-lang/intl_translation/issues/93 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/54181

Comment: i just tested but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I just verified no conflict with `xml: ^4.1.0` using flutter **master channel**.  The conflict still exists on dev, beta, and stable [channels](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels).  I think it will just be a bit of testing before they promote changes [Lukas Renggli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82303/lukas-renggli) mentioned above.